# can I use function generator as electrocutaneous

Tags: arduino, function-generator

I am looking to build a electrocutaneous system to stimulate tactile sensation.

I researched and find we need to provide current wave of ~2mA ~0.2ms ~200Hz.

Can I build a function generator with arduino to use?

Is function generator same as Transcutaneous electrical nerve stimulation system?

Comment: What sort of voltage do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various TENS designs use relatively high voltage (30 to 100 volts), so you will need to somehow step up the voltage and then regulate the current, as Arduino can only give 5 volts and cannot regulate the current. You can build this with Arduino, but you will have to design it very carefully, otherwise you may deliver a dangerous voltage instead.

'function generator' is a common term for all circuits which generate impulses. While some function generators may generate what you need, most generators only output up to 10 volts and cannot regulate the current.